# PostgreSQL запрос

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите, как было бы правильно создать один запрос, в котором бы обновлялись данные сразу в нескольких таблицах?
В MySQL я раньше использовал такой способ

```
UPDATE customer, customer_order
          SET closed = 1, closedAt = NOW() WHERE closed = 0 AND accept = 1;
```

Но в PostgreSQL показывает ошибку

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: UPDATE customer, customer_order
                       ^
```

Не очень хочется делать раздельные запросы. Может есть какой вариант всё сделать в одном?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Нет, нету.** Один `UPDATE` может обновлять только одну таблицу. Указание нескольких таблиц это синтаксическая ошибка.

Чтобы это применилось в базу атомарно, нужно сделать два отдельных `UPDATE` в одной транзакции.

Ситуация несколько отличается для обновления **одной** таблицы на основе значений в другой, фильтруемых с помощью **соединения** (`JOIN`), к примеру. Там можно указать подсоединяемую таблицу в `FROM` и указать условия соединения в `WHERE`.

---

*[Документация по `UPDATE`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)*

Answer (score 4):

Универсальный способ сделать всё что угодно одним запросом - использовать [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html), пишущие запросы полностью поддерживаются.

```
with write_customer as (
    update customers set /**/ where /**/
)
update customer_order set /**/ where /**/
```

По вашему примеру я не понимаю, что и где должно было обновиться в `mysql`, таблицы не связаны между собой и непонятно, какие поля какой таблице относятся. Если же писать надо только одну таблицу, но на основании данных другой - это можно сделать и простым `update`.